# scoring motifs in python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary in python which look likes this:

```
raw = {'id1': ['KKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM'], 'id2': ['KKKKM', 'KKKKKK']}
```

as you see the values are list. I would like to replace the list with a number which is score. I score each character in the list based on their length. if the length is 4 to 9 they would get 1, from 10 to 15 would be 2 and 16 and longer would get 3. then I add up all scores per id and would have one score per id. here is small example:

```
score = {'id1': 3, 'id2': 2}
```

I tried this code:

```
score = {}
for val in raw.values():
    for i in val:
        if len(i) >=4 and len(i) <9:
            sc = 1
        elif len(i) >=10 and len(i) <15:
            sc = 2
        else:
            sc = 3
        score[raw.keys()] = sc
```

it did not give what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your example.

The first is that there is no incrementation of the score. You should initialize a counter in the outer loop, and increment it when iterating over the items in the key.

```
for val in raw.values():
    score = 0
    for i in val:
        ...
        score += 1  # or 2 or 4
```

The second problem is that you need to access the specific key you are scoring when storing the score. As "raw.keys()" returns a list of all the keys, it doesn't make sense to use it when storing value.
Instead, your outer loop should iterate over both key and value, thus allowing you to know what key you are currently using.

```
for key, val in raw.items():
    ....
```

To summarize, here is a working example:

```
score = {}
for key, val in raw.items():  # iterating over both key and value (.items instead of .values)
    cur_score = 0  # initializing the current score counter
    for item in val:  # use readable names!
        item_len = len(item)  # calculated once for efficiency
        if 4 <= item_len < 9:  # the python way to check value in range
            cur_score += 1
        elif 10 <= item_len < 15:
            cur_score += 2
        else:
            cur_score += 3
        score[key] = cur_score
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use the entire list of keys as an index into the dictionary.  Also, you put that assignment inside both loops.  What did you *expect* this to do on each iteration?

First, your outer loop has to iterate through the list of dictionary elements, not merely the values.  You would need something like:

```
for key, val in raw.iteritems():
```

Next, you need to maintain a running total of the scores for the individual strings.  You should look this up ... but the basic idea is

```
    total = 0
    for item in my_list:  # you have to determine what my_list should be
        sc = # score for that item
        total += sc
```

... and finally, after this loop ...

```
    score[key] = total
```

That should get you moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through all the key, value pairs of the dictionary and maintain a running total of the scores for each element of the dictionary values (which is a list in your case).

You can reform your code as follows to get your desired output.

```
raw = {'id1': ['KKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM'], 'id2': ['KKKKM', 'KKKKKK']}

score = {}
# iterating through all the key, value pairs of the dictionary
for key, value in raw.items():
    sc = 0
    # iterating through all the elements of the current value
    for item in value:
        if len(item) >=4 and len(item) <=9:
            sc += 1
        elif len(item) >=10 and len(item) <=15:
            sc += 2
        else:
            sc += 3
    score[key] = sc

print(score)
```

It outputs:

```
{'id1': 3, 'id2': 2}
```

So, the loop, `for key, value in raw.items():` runs for each key, value pair of the dictionary which are `'id1': ['KKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM']` and `'id2': ['KKKKM', 'KKKKKK']`.

Then the nested loop, `for item in value:` runs twice for two dictionary key's value which are `['KKKK', 'MMMMMMMMMMMMMMM']` and `['KKKKM', 'KKKKKK']`.